# Chef: Overriding a Parent's attributes in a cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to understand how to override the attributes of a parent's cookbook. For example, let's say I have the following cookbooks\recipes:

**Parent**

-> attributes -> default.rb -> `default['attribute']['string'] = 'Parent'`

-> recipes -> test_override.rb -> `Chef::Log.info(node['attribute']['string'])`

**Child**

-> attributes -> default.rb -> `default['attribute']['string'] = 'Child'`

-> metadata.rb -> `depends 'Parent'`

-> .kitchen.yml ->

```
  - name: default
    run_list:      
      - recipe[Parent::test_override]
```

When I run kitchen converge on the **Child** cookbook, I expect the Logging to print out 'Child', but instead it prints 'Parent'. Is there a way to override the attribute of the parent with the child?

Answer (score 0):

Chef attributes have a predefined [precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attribute_precedence/). The order of playbook does not matter. When the attribute is defined as `default` in `attributes/` directory it is at the same level, irrespective of whether its in a parent or child cookbook.

Attributes can be defined in:

1. files in `attributes/` directory of cookbook
2. In recipe files in `recipes/` directory
3. Chef environment
4. Chef role

The simplest precedence level is 1 < 2 < 3  < 4.

If you want to set precedence as parent-child cookbook relationship, you should define the attribute in the recipe.

In child playbook's recipe file:

```rb
node.default['attribute']['string'] = 'Child'
```

As mentioned above (and in linked documentation), you could override the attribute from other places as per your requirement.